# converting a file path to a URI

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

When using the secondaryTitle in c++, I have to enter a URI that points to the logo.  The URI fails if I try to point it to any file outside of the app's package.  What I tried to is have the user select the file using a filepicker

```
void App3::MainPage::FindLogo(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    FileOpenPicker^ openPicker = ref new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker->ViewMode = PickerViewMode::Thumbnail;
    openPicker->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".jpg");
    openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".jpeg");
    openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".png");

    create_task(openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([this](Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ file)
    {
        if (file)
        {
            StorageFolder^ folder;
            auto ur = ref new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets//");

            String^ s = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path;


            create_task(StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync(s)).then([=](StorageFolder^ folder){
                create_task(file->CopyAsync(folder, file->Name, NameCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting)).then([this, file](task<StorageFile^> task)
                {

                    logoFile = ref new Uri("ms-appdata:///local//App3//Assets//StoreLogo.scale-100.png");
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

then copy that file and save it in the app directory.  It still fails when using a uri to point to the new copy.

```
void App3::MainPage::kk(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    text = url->Text->ToString();
    ids = id->Text->ToString();
    auto test = ref new Windows::UI::StartScreen::SecondaryTile(ids, "hi", text, logoFile, Windows::UI::StartScreen::TileSize::Square150x150); // Breaks right here
```

// error:  logofile is 0x05fcc1d0

```
    num++;

    test->RequestCreateAsync();



    //auto uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("http://www.google.com");
    //concurrency::task<bool> launchUriOperation(Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchUriAsync(uri));
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
create_task(openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([this](Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ file)
    {
        if (file)
        {
            StorageFolder^ folder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
                create_task(file->CopyAsync(folder, file->Name, NameCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting)).then([this, file](task<StorageFile^> task)
                {
                    String^ path = "ms-appdata:///local/" + file->Name;
                    logoFile = ref new Uri(path);
                });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to copy the picked file into the app package location (InstalledLocation), rather than into an app data folder. The package location is read-only, so CopyAsync should be failing. Use StorageFolder^ localFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder; instead.

Also, you do need the /// in ms-appdata:///local because it's a shorthand to omit the package id, but you need only a single / elsewhere in the URI.

Finally, be aware that tile images must be 200KB or smaller and 1024x1024 or smaller, or they won't appear at all. If you're using photographic images, use a JPEG compression; vector images compress best with PNG. For more on dealing with this, see Chapter 16 of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), specifically "Basic Tile Updates" starting on page 887 and the sidebar on page 899. The content is applicable to apps written in all languages, and it's a free book so there's no risk.

Comment: I just tried that, it still can not find it.  I have updated my post with the updated code.  Thanks.

Comment: It's likely that the file is too big or the image size is too large...see my edited response. You can verify the image by looking in your local appdata folder and seeing what was copied there. If it's over 200K or 1024px in any dimension, the tile won't display it.